# vtk script - Extracting data along a line

Tags: python, extract, vtk

I would like to save data from a CFD computation. I need to extract the data along a line, in a .csv file, using a vtk script. Here is what I want to do:

- 1. plot a line
- 2. save the value of the quantity of interest (1st
     component of the velocity) and its coordinate along the line **(should
     be able to handle unstructured mesh)**
- 3. save the 2 quantities in a .csv file.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
from vtk.numpy_interface import algorithms as algs

""" I/O parameters """
path='path/RESU/20231219-2125/'
in_folder = path + 'postprocessing/'
out_folder = path + 'Profiles3/'
in_casefile = in_folder + 'RESULTS.case'
time_value = 999999.0 # Select the last time value

fields_vector = (
     ("Velocity", 0, None),
)
fields = fields_vector

reader = vtk.vtkEnSightGoldBinaryReader()
reader.SetCaseFileName(in_casefile)
reader.ReadAllVariablesOff()
reader.SetTimeValue(time_value)

x_coord=[0.03, 0.05]

# Can handle several x locations
for Lx in x_coord:
    lineSource = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    lineSource.SetPoint1(Lx, 0, 0)
    lineSource.SetPoint2(Lx, 0.13, 0)
    lineSource.SetResolution(100)
    for i, field in enumerate(fields):
        # Create a probe filter
        probeFilter = vtk.vtkProbeLineFilter()
        probeFilter.SetInputConnection(lineSource.GetOutputPort())
        probeFilter.SetSourceConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())               
        centers_data = dsa.WrapDataObject(probeFilter.GetOutputDataObject(0))
        field_centers = centers_data.PointData[field[0]]
        z_centers_uniq, z_idx, z_inv, z_cnt = np.unique(
                    centers_data.Points[:, 2],
                    return_index=True,
                    return_inverse=True,
                    return_counts=True)
    np.savetxt(out_folder + field[0] , np.vstack((z_centers_uniq,field_centers[:,0])).T, delimiter=',')
```

But it does not work:

```
raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e')
```

I tries to handle this error with the following modifications without success:

```
    index_1 = field[1]
    index_2 = field[2]                
    centers_data = dsa.WrapDataObject(probeFilter.GetOutputDataObject(0))
    field_centers = centers_data.PointData[field[0]].Arrays[0][:, index_1, index_2]
    z_centers_uniq, z_idx, z_inv, z_cnt = np.unique(
                    centers_data.Points[:, 2].Arrays[0].round(decimals=16),
                    return_index=True,
                    return_inverse=True,
                    return_counts=True)
```

May you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how ParaView is involved here.

If you are in a ParaView programmable filter, I advise you to use at most ParaView filters and minimize the use of python, this is less error-prone.

So:

- create a `Plot Over Line`
- `Pass Arrays` to keep only data of interest
- (opt. `Calculator` to extract component)
- `CSV` Extractor to write file

Comment: The goal is to extract directly the profile with the python script without opening Paraview. I modified the post to correct this.

Comment: note that you still can script paraview and my solution works as a paraview script: https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/introduction.html#getting-started-with-pvpython